# Why does summing numbers in ascending or descending sorting change the result?

Tags: python, single-precision

I searched the answer to this question a lot, and I found that, in my case, it's the opposite.

I am trying to sum single precision float numbers in descending and ascending order to figure it out which one gives the smallest error.

Intuitively I would say in ascending order, since adding small numbers you can get a number that can be compared with a bigger one:

In single-precision
10^-8 added 10^7 times will give 0.1 that summed to 1 will give 1.1

The other way around
adding 10^-8 to 1 10^7 times will still give 1 since in single precision the bit is discarded.

However, doing this for a large number of numbers gives me the opposite:

```
def sum_increasing_magnitude(array):
    increasing_array = np.sort(array)
    increasing_sum = np.single(0)
    
    for i in increasing_array:
        increasing_sum += np.single(i)
        
    return increasing_sum
    
    
def sum_decreasing_magnitude(array):
    increasing_array = np.sort(array)
    decreasing_array = increasing_array[::-1]
    decreasing_sum = np.single(0)
    
    for i in decreasing_array:
        decreasing_sum += np.single(i)
        
    return decreasing_sum


values = np.logspace(1,7,7)

decreasing = []
increasing = []
double = []

for val in values:
    array = np.single(np.random.random(int(val)))
    decreasing.append(sum_decreasing_magnitude(array))
    increasing.append(sum_increasing_magnitude(array))
    double.append(sum(np.double(array)))

print(([abs(decreasing[i] - double[i]) for i in range(len(double))]))
print(([abs(increasing[i] - double[i]) for i in range(len(double))]))
```

[3.5390257835388184e-07, 4.4330954551696777e-07, 0.00010590511374175549, 0.006269174667977495, 0.12608919621561654, 12.35097292996943, 406.54364286363125]
[3.5390257835388184e-07, 3.3713877201080322e-06, 7.720035500824451e-05, 0.006757455917977495, 0.02625455378438346, 1.88222292996943, 58020.04364286363]

For 10^7 random numbers between 0 and 1, the ascending sum gave me a way bigger error compared to the descending sum.

Now the question is: why is this happening in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should sum them in ascending order.  You need to think about how floating point numbers work.

Consider, for example, summing the following set:

```
1
2
3
4
1,000,000
2,000,000
3,000,000
```

And lets assume we're using a computer that only holds 6 significant digits.  If you add them in ascending order, you get 1+2+3+4 which is 10, making the sum 6,000,010.

But if we sum them in descending order, you'll get to 6,000,000, and those other numbers are beyond the significant digits of the accumulator, so they do not affect the result and you'll end up with 6,0000,000.

Any time you are using numbers whose range spans the significant digits of the registers, you need to worry about this kind of thing to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: yeah I know, but summing in ascending order gave me a bigger error for some reason